# Best way to detect html element changes?

Tags: java, php, html, sql

I am currently using Java HtmlUnit to load web pages and various Html elements in those pages.  Every 100 ms, I check if there is changes in these elements.

HtmlUnit seems like overkill for just looking for changes in these elements, is there any better way to do this?

I also need to write these results to a sql database, so should I use JDBC, or send them to a php script to write results to the database?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the context of this search. 100ms is pretty frequent and might be an overkill for your server. Nevertheless you can easily do it with a combination of CURL and Regular Expressions. Both are available in any language (including linux command line) so it's up to you what will be the best place to put it.